# jquery datatables column.data undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using row grouping feature of datatable, here is my drawcallback function:

```
oTable = jQuery_1_11('#example').dataTable({
"searching": false,
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"iDisplayLength": 20,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"language": {"infoFiltered": ""},
columnDefs: [{
        targets: 0,
        "visible": false,
    }],
"ajax": {
    "url": "index.php?entryPoint=getTableData",
    "dataType": 'json',
    "pages": "5",
    "type": "POST",
    "data": function(d) {
        d.dbJson = sendJson
    },
    "dataSrc": function(response) {
        return response.aaData;

    }
},
"drawCallback": function(  ) {

    var api = this.api();
    var rows = api.rows({page: 'current'}).nodes();
    var last = null;
    api.column(0, {page: 'current'}).data().each(function(group, i) {
        if (last !== group) {
            jQuery_1_11(rows).eq(i).before(
                    '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                    );
            last = group;
        }
    });
}

})
```

I don't know it's stuck on.

```
api.column(0, {page: 'current'}).data().each(function(group, i) {
```

This is giving the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined

Please help!

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle where the error is reproduced? The code works right away, so you must have something else that are causing the error. BTW, why not use the existing rowgrouping plugin?

Comment: try changing `jQuery_1_11('#example').dataTable` to `jQuery_1_11('#example').DataTable` with a capital `D`. The API you're trying to access is from version 1.10+ which is initialized with a capital `D`.

Comment: jQuery_1_11('#example').DataTable also didn't worked

Comment: actually the table is not initialized on page load, it's actually binded with jquery jstree. When user clicks on any node of jstree the table initialized and created dynamically.

Comment: @davidkonrad can you please elaborate regarding existing rowgrouping plugin.

Comment: @kasimbadami, maybe I misunderstand, but are you not trying to do exactly the same as https://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/customization.html?? Yor code injects a row with the "group" name, as the row grouping plugin does.

Comment: @davidkonrad nope i am not using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked by changing to latest version of DataTables 1.10.6.
Previously i was using  **DataTables 1.10.6-dev**

In jquery.dataTables.js file you can check the very first line what's currently in used.

And by changing

```
jQuery_1_11('#example').dataTable
```

to

```
jQuery_1_11('#example').DataTable
```

Thanks all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The drawCallback is called before the ajax call returned. It is called on the event of first table initialization, and on the ajax callback as well.
If you insert a type check before manipulating the .data() value, it will not crash on the first draw event and it will run on the ajax callback.

```
    function(  ) {

    var api = this.api();
    var rows = api.rows({page: 'current'}).nodes();
    var last = null;
    if(typeof api.column(0, {page: 'current'}).data() !=="undefined"){
       api.column(0, {page: 'current'}).data().each(function(group, i) {
           if (last !== group) {
               jQuery_1_11(rows).eq(i).before(
                    '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                    );
               last = group;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: it's always undefined and thus not going in IF() condition.

Comment: so, if you delete the drawCallback property from the initialization, does the table loads with the ajax retrieved data?

Comment: yes but without grouping. actually the table is not initialized on page load, it's actually binded with jquery jstree. When user clicks on any node of jstree the table initialized and created dynamically.